# In a range of cells find any one of many strings, most of which are not in the same position

Tags: excel, vba

Although I have some experience in VBA I still consider myself a novice.  Just something to keep in mind.

I have a monthly report of a workbook with three worksheets that I am writing a macro for to combine and restructure the file for the output.  My issue is that I have data in one column that contains information that I must extract some text, change the case and write back to the same cell.  The text is, generally, a company name which will not start in the same location from company to company.  Since VBA does not use wildcards (something I am accustomed to) I am finding it difficult to formulate a means to attain my task.  I thought, once I located the 'name' I could reference a table and extract the modified name I need and rewrite to the cell.  Here is an example of some input:

```
Col A                         Col B        Col C
ASTRO #256                    ASTRO        Astro
DEBIT PURCH VISA CHEVRON 02   CHEVRON      Chevron
SMART FOODSERVICE             SMART FOOD   Smart Foodservice
```

The value in column B is what I need to find in Column A and then take the value from Column C moved to Column A

I know I can do countless IF ELSE nests but I would rather have a separate table of col B and C in which to add new accounts as they arise.  But that would require the code to be generic enough so the only updates are to the table and not the code.  I understand I may be forced to do both but I suspect there is a more efficient way to do this.

Any thoughts?  Thanks, Jeff

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58631956/edit) to provide a sample outcome and what you have tried so far?

Comment: As cybernetic nomad implied, you need to clarify your question. Are your columns on the same sheet? are your names on the same row? If the sample your provide is how your data is set up then; all you need is a `For` loop with an `If` statement and use `InStr` to check the value. Please clarify.